# How to convert json-string into CLOS object using cl-json library?

Tags: json, common-lisp, clos

If there is a class and a json:

```
(defclass foo ()
    ((bar :initarg :bar)))

(defvar *input* "\{ \"bar\" : 3 }")
```

How to convert `*input*` into an instance of `foo` using cl-json library?

I guess it should be something like:

```
(with-decoder-simple-clos-semantics
    (let ((*prototype-name* 'foo))
      (decode-json-from-string *input*)))
```

But it produces:

```
Invalid SB-MOP:SLOT-DEFINITION initialization: the
initialization argument :NAME was constant: :BAR.
   [Condition of type SB-PCL::SLOTD-INITIALIZATION-ERROR]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The prototype name is the name of a key in Json to which is associated a Json objet describing the lisp package and classes to use when decoding an object. Did you try first decoding the object as a fluid class instance? if that works, then you can add metadata in Json to specify the class to use with the "prototype" key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the error is that `cl-json:*json-symbols-package*` is bound to the `KEYWORD` package: when JSON keys are turned into symbols, they become keywords which apparently are not valid as slot names.

#### Fluid objects

The following works:

```
(let ((json:*json-symbols-package* (find-package :cl-user)))
  (json:with-decoder-simple-clos-semantics
    (json:decode-json-from-string "{ \"bar\" : 3 }")))
```

*(note: you only need backslashes before double-quote characters)*

You obtain a `FLUID-OBJECT`.

#### Prototype key in JSON data

Now, you can also define your own class:

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defclass foo ()
  ((bar :initarg :bar)))
```

And then, the JSON needs to have a `"prototype"` key:

```
 (let ((json:*json-symbols-package* (find-package :cl-user)))
   (json:with-decoder-simple-clos-semantics
     (json:decode-json-from-string
      "{ \"bar\" : 3 , 
         \"prototype\" : { \"lispClass\" : \"foo\", 
                           \"lispPackage\" : \"cl-user\"  }}")))
```

The above returns an instance of `FOO`.

You can use a different key than `"prototype"` by rebinding `*prototype-name*`.

#### Force a default prototype (hack)

Without changing the existing library code, you can hack around it to change the behavior of the decoding step. The code is organized around special variables that are used as callbacks at various point of the parsing, so it is a matter of wrapping the expected function with your own:

```
(defun wrap-for-class (class &optional (fn json::*end-of-object-handler*))
  (let ((prototype (make-instance 'json::prototype :lisp-class class)))
    (lambda ()
      ;; dynamically rebind *prototype* right around calling fn
      (let ((json::*prototype* prototype))
        (funcall fn)))))
```

The above creates a prototype object for the given class (symbol), capture the current binding of `*end-of-object-handler*`, and returns a closure that, when called, bind `*prototype*` to the closed-over prototype instance.

Then, you call it as follows:

```
(let ((json:*json-symbols-package* *package*))
  (json:with-decoder-simple-clos-semantics
    (let ((json::*end-of-object-handler* (wrap-for-class 'foo)))
      (json:decode-json-from-string
       "{ \"bar\" : 3 }"))))
```

And you have an instance of `FOO`.

#### Recursion

Note that if you define `foo` as follows:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((bar :initarg :bar :accessor bar)
   (foo :initarg :foo :accessor foo)))
```

Then the hack also reads nested JSON objects as FOO:

```
(let ((json:*json-symbols-package* *package*))
  (json:with-decoder-simple-clos-semantics
    (let ((json::*end-of-object-handler* (wrap-for-class 'foo)))
      (json:decode-json-from-string
       "{ \"bar\" : 3, \"foo\" : { \"bar\" : 10} }"))))

=> #<FOO {1007A70E23}>

> (describe *)
#<FOO {1007A70E23}>
  [standard-object]

Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:
  BAR                            = 3
  FOO                            = #<FOO {1007A70D53}>

> (describe (foo **))
#<FOO {1007A70D53}>
  [standard-object]

 Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:
  BAR                            = 10
  FOO                            = #<unbound slot>
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it now, you need to explicitly define prototype class in the same json. But is there a way to use symbol of a class instead, like `'foo` in this case, to avoid modifying JSON if you don't want to pass around meta information?

Comment: Wow  your knowledge of how the library works is impressive! Thanks for bringing up this solution!

Comment: @Zapko Thanks; it helps that the editor can point directly to the source code of the library!