# How to convert json-string into "complex" CLOS object using cl-json library?

Tags: json, common-lisp, clos

I'm coming from this question [How to convert json-string into CLOS object using cl-json library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015871/how-to-convert-json-string-into-clos-object-using-cl-json-library) in which an answer provides a way to instantiate an object of a told class using an input json.

Sadly the answer misses recursivity, as slots of the class top object (that are typed to another class using :type inside defclass) don't get an instance of that class.

How could the answer be modified to achieve that (I'm not yet comfortable working with mop concepts).
Alternatively, isn't there yet already a library that can do such instantiation of my classes from JSON data in a generic and automatic way ?

I thought that would be a very common usage of JSON.

EDIT : This library https://github.com/gschjetne/json-mop seems to do the job, but it is using a metaclass and specific slot option keywords which makes the defclass non-standard to 3rd party classes.

Comment: The thing is, json has no object, just key/values; cl-json requires the "prototype" field in the json data to indicate which type you want to deserialize to. If you add another "foo" field with a nested object, that object needs a prototype too. So I don't really understand what you want to do. Could you write an example input and desired output? I edited the answer to the other question btw.

Comment: JSON-MOP is fine, and you can define custom "encode" methods for third-party class and/or define subclasses of those classes that are of json-serializable-class metaclass (validate-superclass allows this); in that case you need to declare which slots are serializable by repeating the slots names and by adding json-key, json-type

Comment: Thank you, [Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/vin-d/dab2b2a986cbf900681baace270a7db1)

Comment: Both defclass-es define a :type for the slots partner and employed-by so we should be able to use that to infer the type to use for the 2th level JSON objects to change the prototype at each level of JSON object while decoding.
...but that's too cryptic for my current weak level of lisp.

Answer (score 1):

The [sanity-clause](https://github.com/fisxoj/sanity-clause) library allows to take a json with nested objects (I didn't try more levels than the readme examples) and turns them into objects. Besides, it does data validation.

Its example is a bit different than yours. You created objects, encoded them to json and tried to decode them again.

The sanity-clause example starts from a json:

```
{
  "title": "Swagger Sample App",
  "description": "This is a sample server Petstore server.",
  "termsOfService": "http://swagger.io/terms/",
  "contact": {
    "name": "API Support",
    "url": "http://www.swagger.io/support",
    "email": "support@swagger.io"
  },
  "license": {
    "name": "Apache 2.0",
    "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
  },
  "version": "1.0.1"
}
```

It has the three corresponding classes contact, licence and info (top level). In the end, we get an info object where its contact and licence slots are of the corresponding types:

```
(describe #<INFO-OBJECT {1006003ED3}>)
#<INFO-OBJECT {1006003ED3}>
  [standard-object]

Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:
  TITLE                          = "Swagger Sample App"
  DESCRIPTION                    = "This is a sample server Petstore server."
  TERMS-OF-SERVICE               = "http://swagger.io/terms/"
  CONTACT                        = #<CONTACT-OBJECT {1005FFDB43}>
  LICENSE                        = #<LICENSE-OBJECT {10060021F3}>
  VERSION                        = "1.0.1"
```

After the class declarations, this object was loaded with

```
(let ((v2-info (alexandria:read-file-into-string "v2-info.json")))
  (sanity-clause:load (find-class 'info-object) (jojo:parse v2-info :as :alist)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that seem to be a good solution, but I had in mind a solution which doesn't clutter the defclass of the instances you will end up with :
the custom/additional :metaclass , the new keywords :field-type :element-type, data-key, :required.  
I guess those exists because sanity-clause as a validation tool does way more than just Json2CLOS decoding.

Also I've finally found a solution by myself without using the metaclass.

Answer (score 1):

#### Circular structures

First of all, in the example you linked, I have an error when I try to make the "Alice" instance, since its `:partner` slot is `nil` but the declared type is `person`. Either you need to allow for `person` to be nil, with the type `(or null person)`, or you must enforce that all `:partner` are effectively pointing to instances of `person`.

But even if `person` can be `nil`, there might be cases where Alice and Bob are both partners of each other; this is easy to setup if a person can be `nil`, but in the case you want to enforce a non-nil person, you will need to instantiate them as follows: first you allocate both instances, and then you initialize them as usual:

```
(flet ((person () (allocate-instance (find-class 'person))))
  (let ((alice (person)) (bob (person)))
    (setf *mypartner* (initialize-instance alice
                                           :name "Alice"
                                           :address "Regent Street, London"
                                           :phone "555-99999"
                                           :color "blue"
                                           :partner bob
                                           :employed-by *mycompany*))
    (setf *myperson* (initialize-instance bob
                                          :name "Bob"
                                          :address "Broadway, NYC"
                                          :phone "555-123456"
                                          :color "orange"
                                          :partner alice
                                          :employed-by *mycompany*))))
```

Or, you can let some fields unspecified (they will be unbound), and set them later.

Anyway, if you have circular data-structures, the export will fail with a stack overflow (infinite recursion). If you suspect you may have circular data-structures, you need to hash them to an identifier the first time you visit them and encode a reference to their respective identifier the next time you visit them.

For example, a possible way to encode those cross-references is to add an `"id"` to all objects that are cross-referenced from elsewhere and allow a `{ "ref" : <id> }` in place of actual values:

```
[ {"id" : 0,
   "name" : "Alice",
   "partner" : { "id" : 1,
                 "name" : "Bob",
                 "partner" : { "ref" : 0 }},
   { "ref" : 1 } ]
```

This should however be done at an intermediate layer, not hardcoded for all classes.

#### Introspection

If you want to use the MOP to automatically associate slot names to json keys, you can define the following auxiliary functions:

```
(defun decompose-class (class)
  (mapcar (lambda (slot)
            (let* ((slot-name (closer-mop:slot-definition-name slot)))
              (list slot-name
                    (string-downcase slot-name)
                    (closer-mop:slot-definition-type slot))))
          (closer-mop:class-direct-slots (find-class class))))

(defun decompose-value (value)
  (loop
     for (name str-name type) in (decompose-class (class-of value))
     for boundp = (slot-boundp value name)
     collect (list name
                   str-name
                   type
                   boundp
                   (and boundp (slot-value value name)))))
```

They depends on `closer-mop` and extract the interesting information from either a class or a given object. For example, you can extract the names and types for a class, which is useful for knowing how to encode or decode a value of a certain class:

```
(decompose-class 'person)
=> ((name "name" T)
    (address "address" T)
    (phone-number "phone-number" T)
    (favorite-color "favorite-color" T)
    (partner "partner" PERSON)
    (employed-by "employed-by" COMPANY))
```

Likewise, you may want to have the same information for an object, along with the specific values associated with the slot, when the slot is bound:

```
(decompose-value *myperson*)
=> ((name "name" T T "Bob")
    (address "address" T T "Broadway, NYC")
    (phone-number "phone- number" T T "555-123456")
    (favorite-color "favorite-color" T T "orange")
    (partner "partner" PERSON T #<PERSON {100E12CB53}>)
    (employed-by "employed-by" COMPANY T #<COMPANY {100D6B3533}>))
```

You could even define those functions as generic functions to allow different decompositions for special cases.

#### Decoding

Suppose we want to convert association lists to objects (assuming we can easily parse JSON object as alists). We have to define our own encoding/decoding functions, and one issue we will have to manage is cross-references.

First, an helper function:

```
(defun aget (alist key)
  (if-let (cell (assoc key alist :test #'string=))
    (values (cdr cell) t)
    (values nil nil)))
```

A reference is an alist that only has a `"ref"` field, which is a number:

```
(defun referencep (value)
  (and (consp value)
       (not (rest value))
       (aget value "ref")))
```

An object is associated with an index if it has an `"id"` field:

```
(defun indexp (alist)
  (aget alist "id"))
```

Here an `indexer` is just a hash-table, we define `retrieve` and `register`:

```
(defun retrieve (hash ref)
  (multiple-value-bind (v e) (gethash ref hash)
    (prog1 v
      (assert e () "Unknown ref ~s in ~a" ref hash))))

(defun register (hash key object)
  (assert (not (nth-value 1 (gethash key hash))) ()
      "Key ~s already set in ~s" key hash)
  (setf (gethash key hash) object))
```

Then, we define our visitor function, which translates a tree of alist/values as objects:

```
(defun decode-as-object (class key/values
             &optional (index (make-instance 'indexer)))
  (if-let (ref (referencep key/values))
    (retrieve index ref)
    (if (eql class t)
    key/values
    (let ((object (allocate-instance (find-class class))))
      (when-let (key (indexp key/values))
        (register index key object))
      (dolist (tuple (decompose-class class) (shared-initialize object ()))
        (destructuring-bind (name strname class) tuple
          (multiple-value-bind (value foundp) (aget key/values strname)
        (when foundp
          (setf (slot-value object name)
            (decode-as-object class value index))))))))))
```

This does not handle lists of objects, which are likely to be encoded as vectors.

#### Example

```
;; easy-print mixin
(defclass easy-print () ())

(defmethod print-object ((o easy-print) stream)
  (let ((*print-circle* t))
    (print-unreadable-object (o stream :type t :identity t)
      (format stream 
          "~{~a~^ ~_~}"
          (loop
             for (name sname class bp val) in (decompose-value o)
             when bp collect (list name val))))))

(defclass bar (easy-print) 
  ((num :initarg :num :accessor bar-num)
   (foo :initarg :foo :accessor bar-foo)))

(defclass foo (easy-print) 
  ((bar :initarg :bar :type bar :accessor foo-bar)))
```

Simple decode:

```
(decode-as-object 'foo '(("bar" . (("num" . 42)))))
=> #<FOO (BAR #<BAR (NUM 42) {10023AC693}>) {10023AC5C3}>
```

Circular structures:

```
(setf *print-circle* t)

(decode-as-object 'foo 
          '(("id" . 0)
            ("bar" . (("num" . 42)
                  ("foo" . (("ref" . 0)))))))
=> #1=#<FOO (BAR #<BAR (NUM 42) (FOO #1#) {10028113B3}>) {10028112E3}>
```

Comment: **- First of all**, yes good catch about the partner to nil. I should have let the slot unbound, it crashes also on my sbcl (with safety 3).
**- Then sure**, doing Json2CLOS has the multi-reference of an item and circular-reference limitation but my goal was to achieve something similar to JSON.stringify() / JSON.parse() from javascript. So this doesn't sound as a problem for me.

Comment: **- Finally**, **thank you** for kickstarting me with closer-mop. I've finally used it to write my own solution with using 2 more handlers of cl-json and a stack imbricated object references. That was a good exercise for me, I'll post about that later (and I'll be happy to have feedback if it's considered as a naive deisgn/lousy implementation.

Comment: Great to hear. If you post something, consider doing it on the sister site CodeReview. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Here is my code https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231309/thoughts-about-a-json2clos-decoding-using-cl-json but I've just noticed I haven't handled yet json arrays 